# Rails Testing Contents of CSV Download

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing, export-to-csv

I have a project set up to download information from a page as a csv. I'm trying to write a test that ensures the contents of this csv matches what is shown on the site, but I am not sure how to access the contents of the CSV. Here's my current attempt:

```
 test "check_acquired_shares_contents" do       
           data = ["Label Amount Of Shares Share Price Total Price Occurred On From Shareholder Share Transaction Action Share Transaction Type",
                    "Initial 100.0 100.0 10000.0 2001-05-06 CREATE ESPP", "On Date 20.0 10.0 200.0 2012-05-06 Bill TRANSFER INDIVIDUAL",
                    "Label Amount Of Shares Share Price Total Price Occurred On To Shareholder Share Transaction Action Share Transaction Type",
                    "Individual_transfers 10.0 10.0 100.0 2010-05-06 Bill TRANSFER INDIVIDUAL"]
            visit admin_shareholder_path(id: 1)
            find('.action_item', :text => 'Acquired Shares CSV').click
            #binding.pry
            assert data == page.all('tr').map { |tr| tr.text }

    end
```

The data array is what the CSV is meant to contain. However, I think I am not checking the contents of the CSV, because the test always fails.

Anyone have ideas on how to check the CSV contents? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Reading CSV file itself would be good to test the exact CSV scenario here

You can do something like below:

`require 'csv'
csv_data = CSV.read('csv_file_name.csv', { encoding: 'UTF-8', headers: true, converters: :all, header_converters: :symbol})
data = csv_data.map { |d| d.to_hash }`

What u would get is:

`[ {:Label=>"Initial", :Share=>"100.0", :Price=>"10000.0",..}, {:Label=>...}.. ]`

Now you can easily write your test cases by comparing this data and the one you are expecting.

Comment: Thank you for your response! I'll try this out.